# phonegap 3.4.0, project www folder

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build

In my previous project, I used cordava 2.X. When I downloaded 3.4.0, I found there are some difference:

1) There is a WWW folder under Application folder:  Application/www

2) There is also a platforms folder, within it it has android and ios. They both have www folders.

a) Application/platforms/android/assets/www
b) Application/platforms/ios/www

`Question:`

I am starting to put my HTML5 project into phonegap, but which folder shall I put my HTML5 project in? shall I directly work on Application/www or just ignore it and go to sub-directories?

cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the top level application/www folder. When you build your app using the command line tools such as:

```
phonegap build android
phonegap build ios
```

the build process is in charge of updating the plattform-specific www folders. Beware that if you do otherwise, your changes may be overwritten by the build process (if you work directly within the platform-specific www folders).

Best.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In top level www folder, In index.html, I saw it is trying to reference   <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>, but there has no phonegap.js in that folder. But it is available in a) and b) as I listed. Shall I copy that js from a) and b) ?

Comment: The build process takes care of everything for you. Take into account that the phonegap.js file is platform dependent. You should look at the top level www folder as the platform independent code, and the build process is going to deal with each platform specificties. So you should not manually copy anything. Try modifying/building the sample application and you will get a flavor of how it really works. If that helped, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!